# Find the first document after a specified date

Tags: node.js, mongodb, datetime

I have a situation where I need to correlate data between two collections.

I want to get the time from a doc in one collection, and then find either the first doc that comes on or after that time in another collection.

The times are generally not aligned, and there may be cases where there is a significant gap in time between the two.

I'm currently using this (in Node.js, using the native driver):

```
coll.find({ 'TimeIndex': 
              {
                  '$lt': new Date(startTime.getTime() + 1000*10),
                  '$gte': startTime
              }
           });
```

But, baked in there is the assumption that there will be a point within 10 sec. What if there isn't? Then I need to do some sort of broadening search?

I could remove the $lt and just take the first sorted result, but then I fear that the search space will be too large and it will get really slow.

Is there a better way to do this that I'm missing?

Comment: If you are looking for just one document you can use findOne instead of find as you mentioned you want first document after the input time.

Comment: Interesting, but apparently findOne is deprecated in favor of find().limit(1)

Comment: Yeah makes sense, findOne stops scanning as soon as it gets the first document, same thing which limit 1 does. I guess. Though I didn't knew it's deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a good approach here, as query is trying to overcome a certain time gap.
Having assumption that field have an index, then I could suggest to extend time gap to have very safe buffer (and it depends of data load) - like 60 seconds.

It even could be better to retrieve bunch of matched documents and process them client-side than miss something and have an extra round-trip to server.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like this ?

```
coll.find({ 'TimeIndex': {'$gte': startTime}})
    .sort( { TimeIndex: 1 } )
    .limit(1);
```

I don't know about performance however.

If is has performance issue, your approach look good.